# Google custom search placeholder text does not work in Edge browser

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

I have added the following code to the end of the Google custom search script:

```
window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById('gsc-i-id1').placeholder = 'Search';
};
```

This works fine to put the placeholder word "Search" in the search box in every major browser except Microsoft Edge.

Edge returns the following error:

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to set property "placeholder" of undefined or null reference.

I tried a number of adjustments to fix this, but no luck...

UPDATE: Here is a fix until Microsoft fixes this bug:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  document.getElementById('gsc-i-id1').placeholder = 'Search';
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that in Edge the `load` event is firing before the script has run to create `gsc-i-id1`. Since the element doesn't exist yet, the call to set the placeholder ends up running on `null` instead of an actual element, leading to the error.

A quick workaround would be to check if the element exists yet and if not, check again after a timeout.

Ideally you would set the text as part of the searchbox configuration. I don't currently see this as an option in the documentation at https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/ui#elements_searchbox, but you could submit a feature request there to ask for it. Having such an option would both avoid the timing dependency and shield your script from breaking if the id of the element changes in the future.

Comment: I also filed https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/18655840/ to track the issue with the `load` event firing too early in Edge.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was able to fix this by using a setTimeout of 500ms based on your suggestion. However, this is not ideal, so hopefully Microsoft will fix this bug.